# How to abbreviate this condition in Python?

Tags: python

I have a condition like:

```
str1 = "cat, dog, rat"
print( ("cat" not in str1) and ("dog" not in str1) and ("rat" not in str1)) #1
print(any(x not in str1 for x in ("cat","dog","rat"))) #2
```

The problem is #1 condition is too long if I add any others statements so I tranfer it to #2, but #2 return a opposite results, so how to write #1 simply in Python?

Comment: you want `all` not `any`

Comment: or you can put the not outside of the any

Answer (score 2):

As @Sayse mentioned, you should use `all` instead of `any`

```py
words_to_check = ["cat", "dog", "rat"]

str1 = "cat, dog, rat"

if all(word in str1 for word in words_to_check):
    print("All words are present")
else:
    print("Not all words are present")
```

Outputs:

```
All words are present
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.search` here with a regex alternation:

```py
str1 = "cat, dog, rat"
regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(re.split(r',\s*', str1)) + r')\b'
if not re.search(regex, str1):
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```